# win32gui.FindWindow некорректно работает

Tags: python, opencv, screenshots, cv2, win32gui

При захвате окна с помощью `win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)`  черный экран, когда у меня стоит `hwnd = None` все работает! В чем дело?

---

Мой код:

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

    def get_screenshot():
      # define your monitor width and height
      w, h = 1920, 1080

      # for now we will set hwnd to None to capture the primary monitor
      hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Steam')
      # hwnd = None

      # get the window image data
      wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
      dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
      cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
      dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
      dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)
      cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
      cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

      # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
      signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
      img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
      img.shape = (h, w, 4)

      # free resources
      dcObj.DeleteDC()
      cDC.DeleteDC()
      win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
      win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

      # drop the alpha channel to work with cv.matchTemplate()
      img = img[...,:3]

      # make image C_CONTIGUOUS to avoid errors with cv.rectangle()
      img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)

      return img


   while(True):

    screenshot = get_screenshot()

    cv.imshow('Computer Vision', screenshot)`введите сюда код`
    
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```